# Styling asp file upload browse button

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an asp button with certain style. but when i apply the same style to asp file upload control, only background change to that style. The browse button is still the same.

[image]

Asp code  is

```
<div>
    Please Select Excel File: 
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileuploadExcel" runat="server" CssClass="addkey_btn" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" OnClientClick="showDivPageLoading();" CssClass="addkey_btn" />
 </div>
```

CSS is

```
.addkey_btn {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00B7CD;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Altis_Book';
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

I want to apply the same css to Browse button as in Upload button. Any suggestions?

EDIT1
Any pure CSS way of doing this?

Answer (score 11):

It is very difficult to style `input[type=file]` reliably across browsers. The only cross-browser solution is the one demonstrated by @Vitorino, using `label` and/or pseudo-elements to hide the actual `input` and then style that element/pseudo-element instead.

This answer doesn't repeat that, but offers a pure CSS alternative which is browser dependent. That said, this should not be used in production websites, this is just a proof-of-concept or a demo.

Modern browsers are implementing somewhat non-standard extensions to enable user-styling of hitherto nigh-impossible element features. This allows developers to override default user-agent stylesheet to a large extent.

***Custom-extensions***:

Specifically, for `input[type=file]` at least Trident (for IE-10 and above) and Webkit (for Chrome, Safari) allow styling of this element to some extent without resorting to hacks like hidden elements, or absolutely positioned pseudo-elements. For this case, the vendor-specific extensions of our interest are:

1. `-webkit-appearance` (to enable override of user-agent style in Webkit-based browsers)
2. `::-webkit-file-upload-button` (to enable styling of the *browse* button in Webkit browsers)
3. `::-ms-browse` (to enable styling of the *browse* button in Trident-based browsers, i.e. IE)
4. `::-ms-value` (to enable styling of text input in Trident browsers, i.e. IE)

***Caveats***:

1. Unfortunately, there are no `-moz-` extensions for this in Gecko/Mozilla based browsers. Specifically, at least Firefox doesn't allow styling of the *browse* button at all.
2. IE does not allow changing the position of the *browse* button from right to left. Has to be further verified, perhaps it is using `-ms-flex` to control that?

***Demo***:

*Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hxv19bbg/7/*

*Example Snippet*:

The following snippet will work perfectly in IE-10/11 and Chrome-39 (that is what I tested against), but will not work with Firefox.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { margin: 8px; }
input[type=file], input[type=file] + input {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 15px; padding: 4px;
}
input[type=file] + input {
    padding: 13px;
    background-color: #00b7cd;
}
::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #00b7cd;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 15px; padding: 8px;
}
::-ms-browse {
    background-color: #00b7cd;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 15px; padding: 8px;
}
input[type=file]::-ms-value { border: none;  }
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Select File: </label>
    <input id="browse" type="file" />
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can style `label` and place it on top of choose file button

```css
.btn,
label.choose:before {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00B7CD;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Altis_Book';
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
label.choose:before {
  content: 'Choose file';
  padding: 3px 6px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="choose">
    <input id="browse" type="file" />
  </label>
  <input class="btn" type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to disturb the other labels.

Comment: add a class to that `label` and style it